# Stores that accept bitcoins & Alternatives to Bitmit?

Tags: buy-bitcoins

Are there stores that accept bitcoins?
In particular, are there alternatives to the ebay-like website [Bitmit](http://www.bitmit.net)?
Bitmit has shut down, and I am looking for an alternative.

Comment: In order to answer this question properly, you would have to provide more details on what you want to buy and in what country you reside, because answers will differ strongly due to that information. As it is, this question is to broad to answer properly. If you want to keep it like this, you might change it to ask for resources that list businesses that accept Bitcoin.

Comment: +1 Whilst technically, bitcoin.stackexchange does not welcome recommendations for services due to their short-lived nature, I believe there are several sufficiently stable external lists of services that this question may have a stackexchange-compatible, long-term-valid answer in form of pointers to external information.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, plenty of places accept bitcoin.

Here are a few links:

- https://www.spendbitcoins.com/places/ - General list.
- https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Trade - General list.
- http://www.gyft.com/ (enables you to use giftcards at major retailers, from your phone and paid in BTC.)
- http://coinmap.org/ for local places accepting bitcoin.
- http://www.foodler.com for dinner.
- https://www.bitcoinstore.com/ for electronics.
- https://www.corkket.com/ for selling locally.

Comment: ... and in particular, the [section "Material / Physical Products" from the bitcoin.it wiki page](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Trade#Material_.2F_Physical_Products) already mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

[cryptothrift.com](https://cryptothrift.com) is a good site to look at as an alternative to bitmit. They also support Litecoin and other alts as an option

Answer (score 0):

I cannot believe this has not been suggested before, but besides cryptothrift which has already been mentioned, CoinGig is a great eBay-like Bitcoin marketplace like BitMit:

https://www.coingig.com/

Answer (score 0):

I know, I can't believe the Bitmit is gone! I used to sell all kinds of stuff on there!

I read that a new BTC auction site just launched this week. It is called DistractedPuppy.com.

I looked around a little, it looks like a beta, but promising! Maybe there is hope.  ;D

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking for a Bitcoin auction site, like BitMit was, try http://www.halfpricedigital.com

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @cdecker, the answer refers to the business in the link. If the link changes, any content pulled from it would most likely be irrelevant.